# Change text colour for specific user in css (node js chat)

Tags: html, css

I have a simple chat room where users can chat to each other. What I want is that if user1 writes some text and sends it it will appear lets say in white for him and him only any other text from other users would be black colour. I know there is probably a simple CSS solution but I can't figure it out. Below is the HTML code.

```
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<form id="form" action="">
  <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button class="btn-primary"><b>Send</b></button>
</form>
<script src="/torrent-tracker/template/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var url = "http://someurl.net";
  const socket = io(url);

  var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  let input = document.getElementById('input');
  var upime = "<?php echo $upime.": ";?>";
  var uporabnik = "<?php echo $upime;?>";

  socket.emit('newUser', uporabnik);

  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(input.value){
      <?php last_action(); ?>
      socket.emit('PosljiSporocilo', upime+input.value);
      console.log(upime+input.value);
      input.value = '';
    }
  });

  socket.on('DobiSporocilo', Sporocilo => {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.textContent = Sporocilo;
    messages.appendChild(item);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  });

  socket.on('newUserJoined', joinedUser => {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.textContent = joinedUser;
    messages.appendChild(item);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This will be more than CSS, you need to distinguish the messages from the sender vs the others. So before you append them to the message box, you will need to do something to show that the user viewing it is the author or not.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the `$upime` variable holds a username and messages looks like `<li>userName:blah-blah-blah</li>` If so, you need to modify on message listener this way

```
      socket.on('DobiSporocilo', Sporocilo => {
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        item.textContent = Sporocilo;
        if (Sporocilo.match(new RegExp("^"+upime)){ item.classList.add('my-message');}
        messages.appendChild(item);
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
      });
```

and add style

```
<style>
   .my-message{
      color:white;
   }
</style>
```